# Remove weird diamond question mark symbol

Tags: unicode, magento

Any ideas how to remove the weird question mark in the diamond and $0.00 next to it on this page? http://www.happycow.com.au/wholesale

thanks heaps!

Comment: Are you fetching options into the drop-down from the database or are they hard-coded? I would check the db data, it can be messed up like that in the database, so you'd have to clean that up.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the content type to UTF-8.  See if you can add this meta tag to your theme:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
```

See: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_meta_http_equiv.asp

Comment: Ah, so what encoding is the data source using?  It looks like it's coming from a database field?
(You'll need the meta tag to get it to display properly, unless you want to change the data encoding using scripts on the page before displaying it.)